# How to pause this Jquery slider?

Tags: javascript, jquery, plugins, slider, cycle

I have been struggling with this for ever and it's making me pull my hair out!

http://webdesignsalemoregon.com/westernmennoniteschool/

I've got a slider on this home page and I'm trying to figure out how to add a "click to pause" feature to it. (and perhaps a click to resume too, haha)

I believe this is the code generating the slider

```
    var $featured_content = jQuery('#featured #slides'),
    et_featured_slider_auto = jQuery("meta[name=et_featured_slider_auto]").attr('content'),
    et_featured_auto_speed = jQuery("meta[name=et_featured_auto_speed]").attr('content');

if ($featured_content.length){
    var et_featured_options = {
        timeout: 2000,
        speed: 500,
        cleartypeNoBg: true,
        prev:   '#featured a#featured-left', 
        next:   '#featured a#featured-right',
        pager:  '#controllers',
    }
    if ( et_featured_slider_auto == 1 ) et_featured_options.timeout = et_featured_auto_speed;

    $featured_content.cycle( et_featured_options );
}
```

Then I've added a simple button with ID="pauseButton" and put it above the slider. I've also got this code for that button

```
$('#pauseButton').click(function() {
$featured_content.cycle('pause');
});
```

But it doesn't actually pause the slideshow? I believe it's using the cycle plugin from http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle/  and I pulled the pause code from http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle/pause.html

Where am I going wrong?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your script is using `jQuery.noConflict()`, that causes the `$` variable to be reverted back to what it was before jQuery was included. Try replacing all occurences of `$()` with `jQuery()`.

```
jQuery('#pauseButton').click(function() {
    $featured_content.cycle('pause');
});
```

Comment: Wow, I would give you a big wet kiss if I could!
You're a life saver :)